# Custom View inside HorizontalScrollView not scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a custom view inside a HorizontalScrollView like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
         >

        <com.mina.demo.customwidgets.MyCustomView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            />

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

In MyCustomView **onDraw()** method, I draw some text and bitmaps.

the problem is that the width of the custom view becomes larger than the screen width, and wrapping horizontal scroll view does not scroll as if it is disabled.

what can be the reason for this ?

Comment: Can you try changing your custom view's width to fill_parent and see if it change something.

Answer (score 0):

If your `MyCustomView` is always larger than the screen width, then it's safe to set the width of `HorizontalScrollView` equal to its contents. Try the following:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
     >

    <com.mina.demo.customwidgets.MyCustomView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I think the problem right now is that the width of the `HorizontalScrollView` is fixed at `fill_parent`. The scrolling is enabled by default and you haven't manually changed it so that's not the problem.

Comment: When I tried your solution, my custom scroll content were invisible, really don't know why

Comment: Could you post your entire layout file? Merely changing `android:layout_width` shouldn't have done this...

Comment: this layout is inflated to be the item view of a ListView

Comment: Ok...then try setting the `layout_width` of scroll view to 320 (or whatever is the screen size of the AVD you're using).